# convert UTC to clients local date & time using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having some trouble with regex expressions while trying to convert a UTC date format `2014-04-07T01:00:00Z` to the clients local time.

I am not sure why I cannot format the date with this expression;

```
function SetDate(sDate) {
var adjusted = sDate.replace(/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})$/, "$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6");
return new Date(adjusted);
}

document.write(SetDate('2014-04-07T01:00:00Z') ); 

 // outputs Mon Apr 07 2014 04:00:00 GMT+0300 (Middle East Daylight Time)
```

I am looking to format the date to `2014/04/07 04:00:00` but don't know what is wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking into moment js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to take account of the last character `Z` of your string in your pattern:

```
/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}).$/
                                                                   ^
```

Comment: That could probably just be a literal `Z`

Comment: @user3003977: Strange, I have tested it with your example string and it works well.

Comment: @user3003977: paste `console.log(new Date('2014-04-07T01:00:00Z'.replace(/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}).$/, "$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6")));` in http://eval.in and set it to javascript.

Comment: Program Output : Mon Apr 07 2014 03:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)   https://eval.in/133464